# Keda with Rabbitmq and Spring boot

Tags: spring-rabbit, keda

> I am trying to run KEDA with Rabbitmq & Spring Boot. But it is not working. Basically KEDA is not generating Kubernetes HPA object.
>
> I tried sample code (which is provided by KEDA in GO language) & it is working fine.
>
> I have my producer/consumer code written in spring boot. When I am trying to apply KEDA, it is not scaling rabbitmq consumers (basically not even created HPA object)

`https://github.com/sky29/rabbitmq-k8s-broker-publisher-consumer`
  `https://github.com/sky29/rabbitmq-k8s-keda-spring-boot`
  `https://github.com/sky29/rabbitmq-k8s-keda-spring-boot/tree/master/app/myclients`
  `https://github.com/sky29/rabbitmq-k8s-keda-spring-boot/blob/master/app/04_scaled-object-new.yaml`

[image]

Comment: Only difference I can see in provided sample code & my code is: 
- In sample code: producer, consumer & scaledobject - all three are using same connection url
- But in my sample code: scaledobject is using connection url, but producer/consumer is using host/username/password

- Will it create any issue? Ideally my thought was, since scaledojbect is connecting with deployment & rabbitmq broker - it shouldn't make any difference.
Note: Producer & Consumer are working fine (means connection is working pretty fine), only scaling of consumers are not working. HPA object has not been generated.

Comment: Can you retrieve Keda logs? It is supposed to log the error, if any, every time you apply a Custom Resource

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the same. Sharing in case anyone facing the same issue.

I am using KEDA version : 2.8.2

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
  namespace: default
data:
  host: <HTTP API endpoint> # base64 encoded value of format http://guest:password@localhost:15672/vhost
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: host
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: host
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: test-analysis
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion:    apps/v1
    kind:          Deployment
    name:          test-celery      # Mandatory. Must be in the same namespace as the ScaledObject
  pollingInterval:  10                        # Optional. Default: 10 seconds
  cooldownPeriod:   3600                      # Optional. Default: 300 seconds
  minReplicaCount:  1                              # Optional. Default: 0
  maxReplicaCount:  2                            # Optional. Default: 100
  fallback:                                        # Optional. Section to specify fallback options
    failureThreshold: 3                            # Mandatory if fallback section is included
    replicas: 1                                    # Mandatory if fallback section is included
  advanced:                                          # Optional. Section to specify advanced options
    restoreToOriginalReplicaCount: true     # Optional. Default: false
    horizontalPodAutoscalerConfig:                   # Optional. Section to specify HPA related options
      name: keda-hpa-auto-analysis               # Optional. Default: keda-hpa-{scaled-object-name}
      behavior:                                     # Optional. Use to modify HPA's scaling behavior
        scaleDown:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 600
          policies:
            - type: Percent
              value: 100
              periodSeconds: 15
  triggers:
  - type: rabbitmq
  metadata:
    protocol: amqp
    queueName: test_queue
    queueLength: "1"
    activationValue: "0"
  authenticationRef:
    name: trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn
```

Reference : https://keda.sh/docs/2.9/scalers/rabbitmq-queue/